# WPF PropertyChanged is null

Tags: wpf, propertychanged

I have a property in code behind file.

```
private int? selectedTypeID = null;
public int? SelectedTypeID
{
  get
  {
    return selectedTypeID;
  }
  set
  {
    selectedTypeID = value;
    OnPropertyChanged( "SelectedTypeID" );
  }
}
```

This is the code for PropertyChanged. The problem is mentioned in commented line, please see.

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
      /*PropertyChanged appears to be null in some cases while in some cases it is not null. I have also tried to explicity assigning it the DataContext but that does not work as well. */
      if( PropertyChanged != null )
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }

#endregion


//This line is in DataContext file where the problematic property is assigned a null.
editLayerSidebar.editConditionIngredient.SelectedTypeID = null;

//This is the combobox xaml where SelectedTypeID has been bound to SelectedValue.
<ComboBox x:Name="TypeCombo" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,0,0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.IngredientTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:EditConditionListLayer}}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTypeID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" >
```

Why the ProperyChanged is becoming null often causing not updating combobox? What should be the solution?

Comment: Stop setting `propertyName` = null?

Comment: Did you set the DataContext at any point?

Comment: try removing the relative source on the combobox selectedvalue

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're binding the `SelectedValue` wrong. Your `ComboBox` itself does not have any property called `SelectedTypeID`. It should be some property of your view model. In this case the `RelativeSource` should walk up the visual tree to target some source having some `DataContext` you want (in this case I guess it has type of `local:EditConditionListLayer`), the `Path` then should have `DataContext` as prefix:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTypeID, 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:EditConditionListLayer}}}"
```

Also I doubt that even your `ComboBox` itself has the `DataContext` you want, if so it could be:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTypeID, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```